# Main relay click test results

Tags: electronics, relay

Civic vti coupe 1999.

I heard that you can test a main relay by checking for clock with each key turn.  So every time you turn the key you will get hear one click.  Here’s what I found:

1. Lock to accessory: no clicks at all
2. Accessory to run: immediate click, can hear fuel pump prime, another click at end so 2 clicks in total
3. Run to start: clock immediately, car tries to start and cuts out immediately, clicks again.

So definately didn’t get a click on the first turn plus other stuff going on.

Does this mean relay might be faulty or is this all normal/the three click test isn’t for all cars?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would say no,
You cant test a relay by listening for any clicks. Usually when a relay breaks its from a crack that happens at the bend of the switching contacts arm. In many cases the contacts will still go back and forth from 87 / 87a  and make the clicking sound but its no longer connected to the load supply 30.

To test **most basic auto relays**, remove it:

- Give 12VDC to coil (86) and load (30)
- Use a test light clipped to GND and probed on (87)
- Give GND to coil (85)

You should hear a click and see the light. You can also probe 87A when you do not have GND on (85) and it should be lit.

Video trying to explain what I meant in first paragraph
https://youtu.be/6KcKs4wzM9M

Comment: +1 for basic relay testing method, however, your first para could be clearer. I'm still not sure what exactly you're trying to say.

Comment: If your reference numbers are from a circuit diagram, please give a link to it. Otherwise they are meaningless.

Comment: @Alephzero This is standard labeling on basic 4/5 pin of automotive relays. 86 and 85 are for coil. 30 is for load in, 87 and 87A are switched load out. The other 25% of labeling is 1 / 2 for coil, 3 for load in and 4 / 5 for switched loads out....

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I added a video to show and try and explain. I ramble a lot so watching at speed x1.5 may be best. If its against rules to post it  please just delete.